# Switching node version in windows

Tags: node.js, nvm

I could see different version of node are installed in my machine. When I am switching to older version of node using nvm use command, its showing me successful but not reflacting on the console. Any suggestion or idea how to move to lower version of the node from installed list.

```
C:\>node -v
v20.9.0

C:\>nvm ls

    18.12.1
    14.19.0

C:\>nvm use 18.12.1
Now using node v18.12.1 (64-bit)

C:\>node -v
v20.9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 possible issues I can think about:

1. Close terminal and reopen again. When you update nvm version, for some reason running node -v in same terminal returns old result on windows. Closing and reopening terminal helps for me.
2. If reopening terminal does not help, then you may have 2 different installations. node command you run points to something different from the nvm. You can check system environment variables in Windows and see if in path you have 2 different NodeJS installation routes provided. If yes only leave one, so that both nvm and node point to same installation.

Comment: I restarted my machine and check again on terminal but still have the same version that is 20. I check the system variable and didn't find any duplicate entry.